# MySQL select bit field, select value with 0 in front

Tags: mysql

I have an row in my table from my database that contains bits, it is type bit with 4 chars long, bit(4). In this field all my value are stored like this:

```
0001
0010
0100
1111
```

I have tried to select and obtain the exact representation, with the 0 in front of 1 but without luck. I have tried to select the values from the bit field like this:

```
SELECT BIN(field+0) FROM `table` WHERE value=0001;

the result is: 1, how can i obtain 0001;
```

I need this value like so because i want to do bitwise operations in PHP. Thank you in advance.

Comment: what is ur desired output here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **LPAD()** in mysql

```
SELECT LPAD(field,4,'0') 
FROM `table` WHERE value=0001;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
select right(concat(field,'0'),4) from yourtable where bcol='0001'
```